# Keeping Text box on screen, currency converter - HTML5, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8" />
    <title>Pound Euro Converter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ptec.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var euro;

        function ETP(){
            euro = document.getElementById("euro").value;
            var pound = euro/1.17;
            document.getElementByID("answer").innerHTML = "Pounds = " + pound;
        }

    </script>



<body>

    <p id="answer"></p> 

    <input type="text" id="euro"/>

    <button onClick="ETP();">Convert</button>



</body>

</html>
```

The Problem is, after I convert my input (Euro) into Pounds, javascript writes the answer (in pounds) on the screen, but deletes everything else on the screen, including the input box. I want a Converter where The Input box remains on the screen the whole time, where it's just a matter of changing the number in the Input Box and clicking Convert.
Do I have to put the input in some sort of loop?
I know if I could put the input box inside the Javascript function and if I kept looping the function it might work. Has anyone got any ideas. The simplest way to keep the function running and the text box on the screen at all times. ~The same was as in google Translate, except with a currency converter basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the answer to an element. The problem with `document.write()` is it destroys everything on the page.

HTML - somewhere to write the answer

```
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Javascript

```
    function ETP(){
        euro = document.getElementById("euro").value;
        var pound = euro/1.17;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Pounds = " + pound;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SSBGk/)

Comment: Nothing seems to happen when I clicked convert. I might have a mstake elsewhere in my code, I've only started Javascript yesterday, so I'm sorry if I seem a bit slow. I've posted my whole code now, any ideas?

Comment: Look at the way you have written `getElementByID`, it has an uppercase D. Copy and paste from my answer - it should be `getElementById` as above. Javascript is case sensitive so will throw a wobbly when this happens.

Comment: Really sorry, Typo mistake. Put a capital in 'Id' where not necessary. Works perfectly. Thanks for the answer!!